# Date deserializer with local time zome

Tags: java, json, spring, date, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a Date object and setting the local Time Zone. I'm getting the date from the server in UTC and my website hosting is in the same time zone, but when I receive the date the time zone from server and my website. However, client can be in another time zone so I need to set the time in client time zone. In order to change the time zone, I saved it in session in a previous request, but when I'm going to deserialize it, the session is null.

I have a Date paramenter in an object

```
public class WorkDay implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private int id;
 @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomJsonDateDeserializer.class)
 private Date date;
```

Then, my deserializer method

```
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
@Autowired
private HttpSession session;


@Override
public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    String dateString = jsonparser.getText();

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    long createdate = new Scanner(dateString).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+").nextLong();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(createdate);

    TimeZone tz = (TimeZone)session.getAttribute("timezone");
    cal.setTimeZone(tz);

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

}

I saved the time zone in session

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(TimeZone timezone, Model model) {    

    UserAuth user = (UserAuth)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    if(user!= null)
    {

        try{
            session.setAttribute("timezone", timezone);
```

I saved before the timezone in session in a previous request, but in this class, session is null. Is there any way I could get data from session in this class?

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve - a `Date` doesn't *have* a time zone. It represents a single point in time - that's all.

Comment: Still unclear. It sounds like now you're actually asking about session management, which has nothing to do with date deserialization.

Comment: I'm trying to get the timezone from Deserialize class from session. I'm trying to access to session because I saved it because there before. But maybe there is another way to recover the local timezone

Comment: You still seem to have missed my initial point: a `Date` value doesn't have a time zone. It isn't "in" a particular time zone at all. Your `cal` operations are doing nothing, basically. You could just use `new Date(createdate)`. Now you can decide to render that `Date` in a particular time zone - but that's a different matter, and the deserialization part is entirely irrelevant to it.

Comment: Ahh okay, I understand you now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` does not work inside the Custom Deserializer class as the instance of that class is created by `Jackson` and not `Spring`.

As far as getting the `TimeZone` is concerned, `session` is stored on server side and hence, will have server's timezone. So, unless you are setting the "timezone" attribute explicitly with any other value, you can get the default timezone with the below:

```
TimeZone defaultTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
```

Comment: yes, I saved client time zone in session before, but if I can't access to session in Deserializer class I don't know how I could get it

Comment: How are you getting the `session` in controller class?

Comment: This is my contrller `@Controller @RequestMapping("/") public class AuthenticationController { @Autowired private HttpSession session;` And then I saving the session in "home" method I shown in the question @DarshanMehta

Comment: Autowiring `session` and setting attributes inside it as `request` comes in sounds like a horrible idea. Sessions are not thread safe and request to session mapping is not always many to one. Abstracting this out into service method sounds a bit better than this, however, I don't know what the underlying requirement is.